# mPDF footer showing only on last page

Tags: html, footer, mpdf, nette

I have a problem with mPDF footer generating.
I am using mPDF with nette framework

```
<sethtmlpageheader name="default_head" value="1" page="ALL" show-this-page="1" />
    {include #content}
<sethtmlpagefooter name="default_foot" value="1" page="ALL" />
```

Where #content is one or more a tables. Header is on every page, but footer is still only on the last page, no matter how many pages the document has.
Anyone has any idea what i might be doing wrong or forgeting?

Thank you for advice in advance

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you should put `<sethtmlpagefooter>` ahead of the content.

Comment: omg... i hate myself right now... Yup that did the trick. Thank you man

Answer (score 2):

I have got one more solution by which you can add a content only on last page of mPDF.
Please follow below steps

- Add header
- Add footer
- Write your HTML
- Add Footer again (this will be only displayed on last page)
- Output

```
    $header = "Page header for all"; // Will be shown on all pages
    $footer = "Page footer for all"; // Will be shown on all pages
    $lastPageFooter = "Add New text for last page footer".$footer; // Adding new text

    $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
    $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);
    $html = $patientDetails . '' . $reportContent;
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter(lastPageFooter);   // This will display footer for last page
    $mpdf->Output();
```

Hope it helps